# How do I set up DFP to show one set of ads for US/UK and AdSense for everywhere else?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-dfp

As a followup to [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43816/does-dfp-small-business-allow-geotargeting), I'm setting up DFP for a blog and need to show one set of creatives to users from the US or UK, and just let AdSense fill in that ad unit when the user is coming from outside the US or UK.

I've been playing with DFP and the interface isn't terribly difficult... I have already defined my ad units and uploaded creatives. (I also understand how to set placements to geotarget.) However, I'm not sure how to put the pieces together-- for example, I don't know *exactly* how to configure DFP to use adsense ads when the geotargeting doesn't match US/UK. Can someone give me a brief step-by-step answer to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up your "Inventory" which is the spaces available on your site where you can show ads.  In each "ad unit" under inventory, there is configuration for adsense where you choose the colors and such.  If you have no "Orders" that match, adsense ads will show in that inventory.

Setting up inventory and inserting the codes onto your website is all that you really *need* to do to use DFP.  Once this is done, your site will be showing adsense ads through DFP.

To show ads that you negotiate yourself, go to your "Orders", set them up and target the orders the way that you want them.  The most important setting is the order "type".  If you want the order to always show up if the targeting matches, you need to set the type to "sponsorship".  Otherwise the order will compete with adsense on a cpc basis.   Full documentation about the types are here: http://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79283
Once you order is set up you can enable it to start serving ads.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I've found DFP to be a buggy mess (at one point I had to completely archive my order and start a fresh one to get DFP to serve properly) but I finally have it working. The delay between making changes in DFP and seeing those changes on the site (and then the complete uselessness of the debugging panel "delivery diagnostics" report) is maddening! I guess you get what you pay for with this thing.

Comment: DoubleClick used to charge big money for it until Google bought them.  I find that they introduce a lot of non-standard terminology and unnecessary complexity that gives it a much steeper learning curve than necessary.  Once I finally got it all set up it seemed to work alright.

Comment: Ah, your experience is better than mine. I agree that the terminology (and interface) is clunky, but now that I have it set up properly, I still have ads that are not showing for reasons that are unclear, and the ad unit shows as "Unmatched targeting or unknown" in the delivery diagnostics. Totally useless. :-\